# Cannot figure out how to use IF statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a categorical variable for my DB: I want to create the "Same_Region" group, that includes all the people that live and work in the same Region and a "Diff_Region" for those who don't. I tried to use the IF statement, but I actually don't know how to proper say "if the variable Region of residence and Region of work are the same, return...". It's the very first time I try to approach by my self R, and I feel a lil bit lost.

I tried to put the two variables (Made by 2 letters - f.i. "BO") as Characters and use the "grep" command. But it eventually took to no results. 
Then I tried by putting both the variables as factors, and nothing much changed.

----In R-----

```
extractSamepr <- function(RegionOfRes, RegionOfWo){
  if(RegionOfRes== RegionOfWo){
    return("SamePr")
  } 
  else {
    return("DiffPr")
  }    

SamePr <- NULL 

for (i in 1:nrow(Data.Base)) {
  SamePr <- c(SamePr, extractSamepr(Data.Base[i, "RegionOfRes", "RegionOfWo"]))
}
```

Comment: You can use one line `ifelse` to create the category variable as follows `Data.Base$cat_var <- ifelse(Data.Base$RegionOfRes==Data.Base$RegionOfWo, "SamePr", "DiffPr")`. Assuming `Data.Base` is your dataframe.

Comment: there are a few errors in your code... `Data.Base[i, "RegionOfRes", "RegionOfWo"]` seems like it will not work. Too many dimensions. What are you trying to do here? And is the for loop inside the function?

Comment: What are the data types of your region variables? You must compare the same data types for this to make sense. If they are collections, maybe you need something like the `.Contains()` function from C# (sorry not that familiar with R)

Comment: Data.Base is my dataframe, I will try now, thanke @deepseefan

Comment: Basically, I am trying to say to R to look for all the frequencies (i) in my data frame, of Region of Residence (RegionOfRes) and Region of Work (RegionOfWo) at the same time. So for each line to look simultanenesly the two columns. Maybe, I do create a loop ? @RAB

Comment: Both variables are strings composed by to letters (for istance "BO"), the regions-codes. Do you think it would be better if I recode them into numbers? @Okuma.Scott

Comment: @deepseefan, it goes "Error in Ops.factor(Data.Base$RegionOfRes, Data.Base$RegionOfWo_18) : 
  gli insiemi dei levels delle due variabili factor differiscono tra loro" (the italian part can be traslated like this: the two level sets of the variables differ one another).

Comment: @ClaudiaGiuliaTiranti, it will be easier if you can share the output of `head(dput(Data.Base), 10)`. First try @Rui solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ifelse` way proposed in @deepseefan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451454/cannot-figure-out-how-to-use-if-statement#comment103240661_58451454) is a standard way of solving this type of problem.
Here is another one. It uses the fact that `FALSE/TRUE` are coded as integers `0/1` to create a logical vector based on equality and then add `1` to that vector, giving a vector of `1/2` values. This result is used in the function's final instruction to index a vector with the two possible outcomes.

```
extractSamepr <- function(DF){
  i <- 1 + (DF[["RegionOfRes"]] == DF[["RegionOfWo"]])
  c("DiffPr", "SamePr")[i]
}

Data.Base$SamePr <- extractSamepr(Data.Base)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll try it right now! @Rui Barradas!